# Understanding Error Codes in Python and Using Meanful Error Names

Tags: python, error-handling

I understand the basic `try:`  `except:` `finally:` syntax for pythons error handling. What I don't understand is how to find the proper error names to make readable code.

For example:

```
try:
     s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     s.connect((HOST, PORT))
     s.settimeout(60)               
     char = s.recv(1)

except socket.timeout:
    pass
```

so if socket raises a timeout, the error is caught. How about if I am looking for a connection refused. I know the error number is 10061. Where in the documentation do I look to find a meaning full name such as timeout. Would there be a similar place to look for other python modules? I know this is a newbie question but I have been putting in error handling my my code for some time now, without actually knowing where to look for error descriptions and names.

EDIT:

Thanks for all your responses.

would

```
except socket.error, exception:
    if exception.errno == ETIMEDOUT:
         pass
```

achieve the same result as

```
except socket.timeout:
    pass
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you'll have to grab the raised exception, extract the error code stored into, and make some `if` comparisons against [errno codes](http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html):

```
try:
     s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     s.connect((HOST, PORT))
     s.settimeout(60)               
     char = s.recv(1)
except socket.error, exception:
    if exception.errno == errno.ECONNREFUSED:
        # this is a connection refused
    # or in a more pythonic way to handle many errors:
    {
       errno.ECONNREFUSED : manage_connection_refused,
       errno.EHOSTDOWN : manage_host_down,
       #all the errors you want to catch
    }.get(exception.errno, default_behaviour)()
except socket.timeout:
    pass
```

with :

```
def manage_connection_refused():
   print "Connection refused"

def manage_host_down():
   print "Host down"

def default_behaviour():
   print "error"
```

Answer (score 2):

You will get an error with an errno, which is described in the [errno](http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html#module-errno) documentation. 10061 is only valid for WinSock.

Comment: ok so how would I write to catch an exception errno.ECONNREFUSED

Answer (score 0):

According to [socket](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html), socket.error values are defined in the [errno](http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html#module-errno) module.